# A While loop with two different steps/iteration

Tags: equation-solving

I'd like to know if there is a possibility to solve an equation in a `While` loop with 2 different steps. I want the step to be small at the beginning and bigger after a certain value of `sigma` (`sigma` is the parameter that changes).
I don't have an exemple and didn't find anything near it here.
It would look like:

```
If[sigma<0.5,iteration=0.05
Then[While[Solve[hat==0, x],
Else[While[Solve[hat==0, x], with iteration 0.1]]]
```

`hat` is a system of equations (long to obtain and I can't copy everything).
I want to know if it is possible, otherwise I'll just put the results together on a plot.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. E.g.:

```
   iteration = 0.1; j = 0; sigma = 1;
   While[j < 0.3,
   j = j + iteration;
  If[j > .1, sigma = 0];
  Print[j];
  If[sigma < 0.5, iteration = 0.05, iteration = 0.1]];
```

Comment: Yes! Seems like it! Thank you very much!

Comment: Is `, iteration 0.1` doing anything here?

Comment: sure, I meant iteration = 0.1. And all that is of course a quick schematic sketch. Just excercising quick understanding and answering.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I didn't need the first "If" and j, because the second gives the condition if sigma<0.5 : iteration = 0.1, else sigma>0.5 : iteration = 0.05 :

```
    iteration = 0.1; σ = 0; While[σ <1, 
     σ = σ + iteration; Print[σ]; 
     If[σ < 0.5, iteration = 0.05, iteration = 0.1]];
```