# Iterative methods to show effects of convergence

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, functions

I have have been given a task to:
Use simple iterative methods (finding a rearrangement of the equation, x = G(x)) to solve an equation. The result should be a figure illustrating how G'(x) affect convergence, and allow the user to view one step at a time.
For the equation e^x-3x=0 I have the following

Rearrange to find x

```
G[x_] = Exp[x] / 3;
Plot[Exp[x] - 3 x, {x, 0, 2},
     AxesLabel → {"x", "y"}
]
```

to show a graph to find where the roots are approximately and then I follow with the iteration

```
x0 = 0.6;
Do[x1 = G[x0]; Print[x1]; x0 = x1, {6}]
```

I have managed to get up to here but am unable to create a figure to show how `G'(x)` will affect convergence. Any help with this would be highly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Question unclear! In your example, what does the function `G` have to do with the function `Exp[x] - 3`1? It looks to me like you may not understand the principle of using iteration to solve an equation.

Comment: The iteration is not the issue, the code I have offered solves the equation using iteration already, I wish to create a figure to illustrate how G'(x) will affect the convergence of the answer.

Comment: Your arrow `→` is some ASCII symbol while it should be `->`. Your second cell does nothing and generally is nonsense. I recommend _first_ to read the docs: [Do](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Do.html), [Functional Iteration](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/FunctionalIteration.html), and [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22314/a-while-loop-with-two-different-steps-iteration) might serve as a working example.

Comment: Your do loop can be replaced with the simpler `NestList[G, 0.6, 6]`.  I'm not sure exactly what is meant by "a figure illustrating how G'[x] affects convergence" but here's a plot that shows that for your example the iterative numerical procedure will always eventually diverge or land on the ~0.619 solution, and that the ~1.51213 solution is unstable:  `last = 50;
Show[
 Plot[{0.619061, 1.51213}, {x, 0, last + 1}, PlotRange -> {0, 2}],
 ListPlot@(NestList[G, #, last] & /@ (Range[0, 1.4, .2]~
      Join~{1.51, 1.512, 1.5121, 1.51213, 1.6}))
 ]`

Comment: (Also, your Do loop had an extra `]` after the first appearance of x1, which I edited out).

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this will get you started:

```
g = Exp[#]/3 &;
divergeX = 5; (* stopping point for div. to Infinity *)
Show[
 Graphics[{
   Arrowheads[{0., 0.02, 0.}; 0.02],
   Table[
    {Darker@Hue[x],
     Arrow[
      PadRight[
       Clip[Transpose@{
          NestWhileList[g, N@x, # < divergeX+0.5 &, 1, 20]}, {0, divergeX}],
       {Automatic, 2}, x]]},
    {x, 0, 5/2, 1/16}]
   },
  PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, 5/2}}, 
  PlotRangePadding -> {Scaled[0.02], Scaled[.05]}, Frame -> True],
 ParametricPlot[{{g'[x], x}, {x, x}, {Nest[g, 0.6, 20], x}}, {x, 0, 5/2}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

(The arrows show the direction of the iterates, as well as connecting them.)

Comment: Cheaty upvote-gathering pretty figures. +1

Comment: @LLlAMnYP Thanks. So far hasn't garnered that many votes. :) I did try making each step an arrow, but they were too crowded to make an effective presentation.